# Upload lambda function.zip with small size

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I've 2 `aws-lambda` projects.

the first one is using `serverless-bundle`.

[serverless-bundle.github](https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-bundle)

when I deploy the first project, I can see below logs

```
(...)
Serverless: Uploading service hello.zip file to S3 (34.56 KB)...
Serverless: Uploading service bye.zip file to S3 (12.34 KB)...
(...)
```

each function.zip has a small size and different size.

and

the second project is using `serverless-plugin-typescript`

[serverless-plugin-typescript](https://github.com/prisma-labs/serverless-plugin-typescript)

and

```
(...)
Serverless: Uploading service hello.zip file to S3 (22.83 MB)...
Serverless: Uploading service bye.zip file to S3 (22.83 MB)...
(...)
```

each functions.zip has the same size and it has a bigger size than the first project's

I am going to use `typescript`, so I can't use `serverless-bundle` because they don't support `ts` yet.

so, my question is how can I reduce the functions.zip size like using `serverless-bundle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless framework now has native support for using typescript via `aws-nodejs-typescript` template.

For new projects you can create them using `serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript && npm install`

For existing projects, you just need to include `serverless-webpack`
 plugin. 
you can use serverless-webpack like this.

```
service:
  name: my-functions    
# Add the serverless-webpack plugin
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
```

In your case, all the zip files are different size because, the first method 'serverless-bundles' is an extension of `serverless-webpack`

Comment: it can reduce the `.zip` file's size?

Comment: yes, it uses `webpack` bundler, therefore it will not include every node_modules, it will include the minimum files required to run your project, it will also has support for `code minification`.

Comment: try changing the plugin to `serverless-webpack` from `serverless-plugin-typescript`

Comment: try and let me know. please be aware that webpack is by default try and minify all the modules that you are using. the `minimize ` process may fail for some modules. I had to disable `minimize`

Comment: it's definitely reduced, but the different function in the same `.ts` has same size

Comment: are you getting multiple zip file produced

Comment: they  might have similar sizes. not same,  compare the sizes in bytes

Comment: its impossible to have the same size unless both the lambdas are same

Comment: let's start beginning, 
I have 2 files `handler1.ts`, `hander2.ts`.
each `handler` have  `hello#()` and `bye#()`. (`#` is the number of handlers).
`handler1.ts` imports `moment` and `handler2.ts` doesn't.

And, `hello1()` is using `moment` in code, but `bye1()` doesn't.

`hello2()` has more dummy string than `bye2()`.

Finally, I deploy them, 

`hello1.zip` and `bye1.zip` have same size and 
`hello2.zip` and `bye2.zip` have the same

Comment: can't you open each zip file and see whats inside, see the code, compare,

Comment: `hello1.zip` and `bye1.zip` have same `handler1.js` and `handler1.js.map`,
`hello2.zip` and `bye2.zip` are in same

Comment: are you saying both files has the exact same content. thats impossible

Comment: nono, I mean, `hello1.zip` and `bye1.zip` have `handler1.js`  and `hello2.zip` and `bye2.zip` have `handler2.js` , `handler1.js` and `handler2.js` are different

Comment: 2 functions each `handler#.js`. total 4

Comment: you will get one zip file per lambda functions, aren't you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203872/discussion-between-zynkn-and-arun-k).